# Does Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition support IntelliSense for creating tables?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, azure-devops, intellisense

I have just begun to use Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition. I'm loving it so far, but there doesn't seem to be any IntelliSense support in the editor where you create tables. It also appears you cannot add a table graphically like you can in SSMS.

Is this true? Are these features missing, or have I just not found how to turn them on?

If they're missing, are there any workarounds or plug-ins that can make my workflow easier? I shouldn't really need these features, but they help me so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got into a habit of just creating the table in SSMS and then using the create function to get the text to create the table, then move that over to the database project, as a new file.

Just remember that every constraint will be in it's own file, and you can't copy files in the database project, from my experience.